# select data where %column% like $variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table name `deny_keywords` in database with this structure:

| id | word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | thief |
| 2 | crook |
| 3 | killer |

and I have an input that user can send a text and this text Placed in variable name `$user_text`.

Now I want to check if `$user_text` includes any of deny keywords or no.

Is there a way to do this just using SQL?

A way like this:

```
SELECT * FROM deny_keywords WHERE %word% like $user_text;
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Thank you for your attention
The user input has been sanitized before using it in the query, and I am sure that the user input is not dangerous

Comment: "Sanitized" is not effective. That assumption may be invalidated in the future, like maybe someone bypasses that inadvertently. You *must* use placeholders whenever possible, it's the only way to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `fulltext index` on the `word` column of the `deny_keywords` table to accomplish this.

To create the index you would run:

```
alter table deny_keywords add fulltext(word);
```

To use the index in the query you are trying to run:

```
select *
from   deny_keywords
where  match(word) against ('$user_text' in natural language mode);
```

A fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/443eb6/1/0

For security reasons, you should use mysqli or PDO, where you prepare the statement and bind the `user_text` variable as a parameter. That's a separate discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found and it works:

```
SELECT * FROM deny_keywords WHERE INSTR('{$user_text}' , `word`) > 0
```